# How to figure out the BCD my chainring has

Tags: mountain-bike, chain, crankset, chainring, diamondback

I have a [2017 Diamondback Line](https://www.rei.com/product/116941/diamondback-line-275-bike-2017). My chain has come off a few times and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/MTB/comments/8n2z61/replacement_chain_guide_piece_for_diamondback_line/) post says get [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D3FG5EY) chainring. I wanted to confirm my bike requires a 104 mm bolt pattern but don't know how to do that; the specs only say "Alloy arm with 32T single ring."

I may not need a new chainring, it's probably my shifting because it usually only happens when I am pedaling hard and in a higher gear (not sure if lower or higher but a gear that requires more effort to pedal) but lets assume I do.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Uh, measure it?  Granted this is a little tricky, but there's probably a table on the web somewhere.  Yep, here: https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/pages/how-to-measure-bolt-circle-diameter-bcd

Comment: Or, better still, Sheldon: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-bcd.html

Comment: Do you suspect your chainring or chain is worn?  Have you measured them?  Posting a photo may help.

Comment: @Criggie I don't think my chain is. My Chainring my be in the early stage of worn. I added pictures

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/55802#55802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bolt center diameter is just the circle around the crank axle axis that the center point of the chainring bolts lie on.

If you have a even number of bolts the diameter is fairly easy to measure. Pick two bolts where a line between them goes through the axle axis. You can make some sort makeshift calipers if the crank arm gets in the way.

If you have an odd number of bolts you can measure between the axle and a bolt and double it, or if the bolts are evenly spaced measure between bolts and look up the BCD on [this page](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-bcd.html).

When ordering a chainring make sure you get one which has the same bolt spacing pattern, although from [this page](https://www.performancebike.com/diamondback-line-27.5-mountain-bike-2017-performance-exclusive-white-31-5627-whi-p/p941911) I'd say you have evenly spaced bolts.

A narrow-wide chainring may help retain the chain, but they work best with a clutch derailleur. The reason you are having  trouble in higher gears (smaller sprockets) is that the chain is under less tension.

If you do order a narrow-wide ring, make sure it is compatible with the number of speeds of your drivetrain.

Comment: I've never had good results using calipers, especially when some BCDs are only a couple millimetres different.  So I print out the wolftooth PDF at 100% scaling and put the old chainring on top.  Much easier.    
 https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0230/9291/files/Measure_BCD_5ad6ccfa-f146-4048-ac0f-e2279602c9e1.pdf

Comment: @Criggie Nice. I was not aware of that page. If one wanted a less cluttered version it would be pretty easy to create your own with a graphics program.